# What's the meaning of "pretty darn foxy" "yourself"?

Tags: meaning

> I think you're **pretty darn foxy** **yourself**. Lady Lisa, I'll love until
>   the end of time.

quoted from the script of movie 'Pixels(2015)'

What's the meaning of "pretty darn foxy" "yourself"?

I guess pretty darn foxy means pretty (damn) sexy,

but what is the role of 'yourself' in the sentence?

Comment: You haven't given the full context, so here's [a link to the subtitle file](http://subscene.com/subtitles/pixels-2015/english/1203161). The reason for including the reflexive pronoun is *emphasis*. The speaker has just been ***praised*** by whoever he's talking to, and he's returning the compliment - as a "balanced pair" of statements, similar to *"I like you, John", "And I like **you**, Jane!"*. The cited example is much the same as *"**You** are pretty foxy **too**"* - except that probably the speaker is a male addressing a female, and she probably didn't actually say ***he*** was "foxy".

Comment: In American slang, this return of the compliment is often "back at ya", i.e. {I say the same thing} back at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "pretty darn foxy" means very sexy.

The yourself is added for emphasis. It wouldn't be used if only Lady Lisa's sexiness was being discussed. So Lady Lisa might have said something like "Lady Morgana is very beautiful" to which the gentleman would reply "I think you're pretty darn foxy yourself. ..."

So if the gentleman and Lady Lisa were discussing the weather then the gentleman would change the subject by just saying "I think you're pretty darn foxy. Lady Lisa, I'll love until the end of time."

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the meaning of "pretty darn foxy."

The "yourself" redirects the adjective phrase to apply to a person who is different than the person the phrase was just applied to, more specifically the person who is being spoken to directly.